# Determine Heartrate Zones with Sport Watches

Tags: training, heart-rate

I have read that the usual way to determine the maximum Heart Rate is to do a lactat test or so. Is it possible to determine Heart Rate Ranges with a watch only? I have read about the Ownzone functionality of Polar watches but could not find a valid review. 
So, is this possible and reliable? And if so what is this functionality called so I can do a good google search for it.

Comment: You can always exercise until you pass out from exhaustion, and note your heart rate just before you become unconscious.  But note that many heart rate monitors will misread at peak exertion.

Comment: Generally the rule is 220-age to get your upper limit. This is hot and miss but will get you started. If you find you can run for 2hours in zone7 you need to tweak the zones. I'm not familiar with Polar but Garmin and Fitbit are easily tweaked within there own application

Comment: @DanK that widely quoted formula isn't even a good representation of the average case, and the average case isn't all that useful for an individual anyway

Comment: Values of chest strap and sportswatch with wrist sensor widely differ, as I found out from own experience. During intense effort the watch would quite often read values beneath 100bpm.

Comment: The question is rather: Do I have to know my maximum Heartrate or can a watch determine the Heartrate Zones by itself